# How to override media.phtml in my custom magento module?

Tags: magento

I am working on a custom module which takes product images from external server. I have overridden a few functions to get the required result.

But I have to override `base/default/template/catalog/product/view/media.phtml` inside my custom module.

I tried to do this from `default/layout/MY_MODULE.xml` but that did not work for me.

How do I override the `media.phtml` inside `default/MY_MODULE`.

Comment: How did you do that inside your layout file? Is your layout file included to layout (does other changes in this file work)?

Comment: thanks for your response. I tried again and added inside mymodule.xml
 <catalog_product_view>
            <reference name="product.info">
                <block type="product_view_media" name="product.info.media" as="media" template="catalog/product/view/media.phtml">
                    <action method="setTemplate"><template>MY-MODULE/catalog/product/view/media.phtml</template></action>
                </block>
            </reference>
        </catalog_product_view> Now it works.
As I am new to magento, I want to know is this the correct way to override template file in custom module?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think calling `setTemplate` method is not the right way to override template file in your case. For me it looks a bit redundant and unclear: you are assigning template to block and the immediately reassign it with action. I would do this way:

```
<catalog_product_view> 
    <reference name="product.info"> 
        <block type="catalog/product_view_media" name="product.info.media" as="media" template="MY-MODULE/catalog/product/view/media.phtml" />
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

I think you could also reference to `product.info.media` directly and call `setTemplate` action there

Comment: I tried <catalog_product_view> 
    <reference name="product.info"> 
        <block type="catalog/product_view_media" name="product.info.media" as="media" template="MY-MODULE/catalog/product/view/media.phtml" />
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view> and it works. Thanks